# How do I create a basic jquery loop?

Tags: jquery, loops, slider

I'm trying to create a simple loop that will go round and round and can be stopped and started.

I tried calling itself such as this

```
var theloop = (function(){

            var theloop = (function(){

            $('#goldspot-2012 ul#goldspot-2012-list li').eq(currentItem).removeClass('current').fadeOut(500);
            $('#goldspot-2012 ul#goldspot-2012-list li').eq(currentItem+1).addClass('current').fadeIn(500);
            $('#gs-controls ul li').eq(currentItem).removeClass('current');             
            $('#gs-controls ul li').eq(currentItem+1).addClass('current');          

            if (currentItem == items -1){
                currentItem = 0;
                theloop();
            }

            else {
                currentItem++;  
                theloop();
            }



        });
```

which just errors out as I imagine its stuck in some endless loop

I've also tried

```
var theloop = setInterval(function(){

            $('#goldspot-2012 ul#goldspot-2012-list li').eq(currentItem).removeClass('current').fadeOut(500);
            $('#gs-controls ul li').eq(currentItem).removeClass('current');                         

            if (currentItem == items -1){
                currentItem = 0;
            }

            else {
                currentItem++;  
            }
            $('#goldspot-2012 ul#goldspot-2012-list li').eq(currentItem).addClass('current').fadeIn(500);
            $('#gs-controls ul li').eq(currentItem).addClass('current');

        }, 5000);
```

but this can't be stopped and started easily.

Can anyone just show me a basic loops that will keep going until you stop it or is one of the two above workable with a little tinkering?

Thanks

Comment: To write a loop, use the JavaScript loop constructs such as `for` or `while`, as in `for (var i=0; i<items; i++) {do stuff}`. If you really want to use recursion for your loop, then remove the call to `theloop()` after the `urrentItem = 0;` statement, so it will stop running.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        var cycler = true;
        var theloop = (function(){

        $('#goldspot-2012 ul#goldspot-2012-list li').eq(currentItem).removeClass('current').fadeOut(500);
        $('#goldspot-2012 ul#goldspot-2012-list li').eq(currentItem+1).addClass('current').fadeIn(500);
        $('#gs-controls ul li').eq(currentItem).removeClass('current');             
        $('#gs-controls ul li').eq(currentItem+1).addClass('current');          

        if (currentItem == items -1){
            currentItem = 0;
        }

        else {
            currentItem++; 
        }

        if(cycler) theloop();

        });
```

This gives you the chance to stop the infinite loop. Place some button or code that sets cycler to *false* when you need to stop the loop.